# GDAL ECW Support on OSX

Tags: gdal, installation, osx

I have a large number of ECW format raster images and would like to use with GDAL (and ultimately in QGIS) on Mac OSX.

Having seen that there is no official ESRI support for the ECW library on any other platform other than Windows, I managed to get hold of the old version of the libecwj2-3.3 library. There are a few versions knocking around, but none of them will successfully compile.

Anyone had any success compiling the ECW library on OSX (10.6.7) and then compiling GDAL with ECW support.